# $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] empty

Tags: php, authentication, titanium, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

EDIT: Problem isn't with PHP, I was using cURL wrong. Updated question to show problem I'm having with XHR.

Summary: Can't get username to PHP using XHR:

```
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.timeout = 1000000;
xhr.open("GET","http://myapi.com/test", false, 'user', 'pass');
xhr.send();
```

And in my PHP script, I'm trying to access the username with this:

```
<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']; ?>
```

No matter what I try it's always empty.

Is there some PHP setting that I need to configure?

More info: PHP Version 5.2.13, Apache, MAMP

Comment: Did you try sending the WWW-Authenticate header? See the example at http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: Have you checked to see if `$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']` is being set?

Comment: You also have tried a normal request, to verify that your XHR is working at all, right? I don't see you calling xhr.send()

Comment: Closing out this question for a better version here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037405/serverphp-auth-user-empty-with-xhr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://www.webtoolkit.info/djs/webtoolkit.base64.js"></script>
<script>
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.timeout = 1000000;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
    alert('Server said: '+xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://myapi.com/test', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('user:pass') );
xhr.send('');
</script>
```

(For the sake of courtesy, you should download webtoolkit.base64.js and serve it from your own server.)

Keep in mind that you can't do cross-domain requests with XHR; your JavaScript and PHP have to be served from the same domain.

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] can be empty if you are running php as CGI. Refer http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html

Comment: @dskanth: Yeah, I also saw that in the comments in the PHP docs. But apparently that wasn't the problem in this case. Personally, I think using Basic Auth is usually a poor strategy - a security risk, and generally causes extra headaches here and there.