# $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] is empty

Tags: php

I tried to update the php version of my VPS but it didn't work and my provider didn't help me well, so i downgrade it to the previous version.

I am now working with PHP 5.2.17 (cli). Everything was working properly in this version.

Since this upgrade and downgrade, the variable `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` is empty. (In the php.ini, `register_globals` is 'on' and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is properly working).

It ask me properly my username and password and i success to connect but i need to use `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

I tried `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`, `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`,  `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` nut none is working. (but im never getting any error, just a blank value...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found the answer thanks to 'mbinette'.

In my PHP configuration, the handler of PHP 5 was CGI, and this type of authentication doesn't work with PHP CGI. So i changed it to suPHP (which is supposed to be the default one on APACHE).

[Find here](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/http-auth-php-cgi.html) a post explaining a way to use CGI and PHP_AUTH, but i tried and it wasn't working.

[Find here](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/MorePhphandlers) some explanations about php handlers

Comment: Glad you found the solution! I honestly didn't have any other idea of what it could be (the only problem I ever had about that was because of safe-mode)..! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Is safe mode activated? That might be your problem...

> As of PHP 4.3.0, in order to prevent someone from writing a script
>   which reveals the password for a page that was authenticated through a
>   traditional external mechanism, the PHP_AUTH variables will not be set
>   if external authentication is enabled for that particular page and
>   safe mode is enabled. Regardless, REMOTE_USER can be used to identify
>   the externally-authenticated user. So, you can use
>   $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'].

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: In my php.ini file, i have : safe_mode = Off

Comment: Are you sure the problem comes from PHP? (and not something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037046/serverphp-auth-user-empty ?). Also, can you make sure error_reporting is on and that there is no errors being thrown prior to that?

Comment: i see it may not work with php cgi, but how can i know which handler to use ?

I can choose between : suphp, dso, cgi and none ?