# Why are $_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_USER”] and $_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_PW”] not set? PHP 5.5.31

Tags: php, apache, ssl, oauth-2.0

In my project i am using REST API with oauth 2.o authentication, everything works fine but recently i was upgraded php version to 5.5.31;

After that change 
`$_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_USER”]` and `$_SERVER[“PHP_AUTH_PW”]` are not set,
so i am not able to authenticate users.

Thanks for your helping hand.

Comment: you can this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558025/serverphp-auth-user-is-empty

Comment: my php handler is CGI.

Comment: ok, you can change it or write htaccess file

Comment: https://theshosting.com/knowledgebase/329/How-to-change-PHP-handler-from-DSO-modphp-to-suPHP-on-cPanel-Server.html

Comment: So i changed my php handler CGI to suPHP, and it works for me; thanks Gouda Elalfy.