# Missing variables from $_SERVER

Tags: php

In the PHP source code, I echo out `$_SERVER` in one of my domain on server A and got returns me a list of data include `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `GATEWAY_INTERFACE` and etc. However, in the another domain in server B didn't return me anything when I echo out same things. Can I know why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_SERVER\['PHP\_AUTH\_USER'\] is empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558025/serverphp-auth-user-is-empty)

Comment: As its name suggests, `$_SERVER` prints server variables so if you switch servers output will be different.

Comment: See the first paragraph on the [$_SERVER PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php): *"There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these"*

Answer (score 1):

Just summarizing the comments, including my own.

> The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.

from *[PHP manual on $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)*

While most servers will provide [at least certain values](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) within `$_SERVER`, there are no guarantees. Either design your code in a way that does not depend on the content of `$_SERVER`, or make sure that the very server you are going to use in production *does* in fact provide the values you need.